# htaccess and DNS issues, unable to get website directing properly

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, dns

so we have 2 domains   bids.ca  and  bidscaribbean.com. This is a (seemingly) simple task of making them point to different files/directories on the same server when they are entered in a browser.

Right now,  bidscaribbean.com redirects to:  bids.ca/caribbean/bids_style/
however, www.bidscaribbean.com redirects to: www.bidscaribbean.com/caribbean/bids_style/

bids.ca is working perfectly, however what I'm LOOKING for is bidscaribbean.com to point to:
biscaribbean.com/caribbean/index.php

or

www.biscaribbean.com/index.php (just an index.php in a different subfolder)

This is what I came up with for my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bidscaribbean.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.bidscaribbean.com/caribbean/index.php [L,R=301]
```

and here is my DNS file:

```
$TTL 7200
bidscaribbean.com. IN SOA dns.bids.ca. hostmaster (
        2011103103
        3600
        3600
        3600
        3600
        )
bidscaribbean.com.      IN      NS      dns.bids.ca.
bidscaribbean.com.      IN      NS      dns2.bids.ca.
; End SOA Header


bidscaribbean.com. in   a       198.164.196.225
www     in      cname   bidscaribbean.com.


bidscaribbean.com.  in      mx      10      aspmx.l.google.com.
bidscaribbean.com.  in      mx      20      ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
bidscaribbean.com.  in      mx      20      ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
bidscaribbean.com.  in      mx      30      ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
bidscaribbean.com.  in      mx      30      ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
bidscaribbean.com.  in      mx      30      ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
bidscaribbean.com.  in      mx      30      ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

It's not working however, and the weird part is that when I ping
bidscaribbean.com  it goes to - 198.164.196.77
but if I ping:
www.bidscaribbean.com  it goes to - 198.164.196.225

I'm completely stumped. As far as my htaccess file goes, it seems correct based on the research I've done, not sure what might be wrong in the whole equation

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that simply a problem with your Apache's virtual hosts ?
It seems that you only need to put something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path_to_your_bids.ca_directory

    ServerName bids.ca
    ServerAlias www.bids.ca
    ServerAdmin admin@bids.ca

    <Directory /path_to_your_bids.ca_directory>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /path_to_your_bidscarribean.com_root_directory

     ServerName bidscarribean.com
     ServerAlias www.bidscarribean.com
     ServerAdmin admin@bidscarribean.com

     <Directory /path_to_your_bidscarribean.com_directory>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

In your apache's vhost file.
Hope it'll help.